# Kubernetes : 0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules. preemption

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra

I'm experiencing this issue: `Pending` Pod due to `nodes didn't match pod anti-affinity rules`

```
    NAME                                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE   IP           NODE                        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
    demo-dc1-default-sts-0                              0/2     Pending   0             38m   <none>       <none>                      <none>           <none>
    demo-dc1-default-sts-1                              1/2     Running   0             62m   10.244.0.6   k8ssandra-0-control-plane   <none>           <none>
    demo-dc1-default-sts-2                              1/2     Running   0             17h   10.244.1.9   k8ssandra-0-worker          <none>           <none>
    k8ssandra-operator-7998574dd5-567qq                 1/1     Running   1 (72m ago)   18h   10.244.1.7   k8ssandra-0-worker          <none>           <none>
    k8ssandra-operator-cass-operator-7599b94d9d-s7nrr   1/1     Running   2 (72m ago)   18h   10.244.1.2   k8ssandra-0-worker          <none>           <none>
```

Output of `kubectl describe pod` :

```
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe pod demo-dc1-default-sts-0 -n k8ssandra-operator
    Name:             demo-dc1-default-sts-0
    Namespace:        k8ssandra-operator
    Priority:         0
    Service Account:  default
    Node:             <none>
    Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/created-by=cass-operator
                      app.kubernetes.io/instance=cassandra-demo
                      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=cass-operator
                      app.kubernetes.io/name=cassandra
                      app.kubernetes.io/version=4.0.1
                      cassandra.datastax.com/cluster=demo
                      cassandra.datastax.com/datacenter=dc1
                      cassandra.datastax.com/node-state=Ready-to-Start
                      cassandra.datastax.com/rack=default
                      controller-revision-hash=demo-dc1-default-sts-7676c86675
                      statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=demo-dc1-default-sts-0
    Annotations:      k8ssandra.io/inject-secret: [{"name":"demo-superuser","path":"/etc/secrets/demo-superuser","containers":["cassandra"]}]
    Status:           Pending
    IP:               
    IPs:              <none>
    Controlled By:    StatefulSet/demo-dc1-default-sts
    Init Containers:
      server-config-init:
        Image:      datastax/cass-config-builder:1.0-ubi7
        Port:       <none>
        Host Port:  <none>
        Limits:
          cpu:     1
          memory:  384M
        Requests:
          cpu:     1
          memory:  256M
        Environment:
          POD_IP:                      (v1:status.podIP)
          HOST_IP:                     (v1:status.hostIP)
          USE_HOST_IP_FOR_BROADCAST:  false
          RACK_NAME:                  default
          PRODUCT_VERSION:            4.0.1
          PRODUCT_NAME:               cassandra
          CONFIG_FILE_DATA:           {"cassandra-env-sh":{"additional-jvm-opts":["-Dcassandra.allow_alter_rf_during_range_movement=true","-Dcassandra.system_distributed_replication=dc1:3","-Dcassandra.jmx.authorizer=org.apache.cassandra.auth.jmx.AuthorizationProxy","-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-jaas.config","-Dcassandra.jmx.remote.login.config=CassandraLogin","-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"]},"cassandra-yaml":{"authenticator":"PasswordAuthenticator","authorizer":"CassandraAuthorizer","num_tokens":16,"role_manager":"CassandraRoleManager"},"cluster-info":{"name":"demo","seeds":"demo-seed-service,demo-dc1-additional-seed-service"},"datacenter-info":{"graph-enabled":0,"name":"dc1","solr-enabled":0,"spark-enabled":0},"jvm-server-options":{"initial_heap_size":512000000,"max_heap_size":512000000},"jvm11-server-options":{"garbage_collector":"G1GC"}}
        Mounts:
          /config from server-config (rw)
          /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-cfdtc (ro)
    Containers:
      cassandra:
        Image:       k8ssandra/cass-management-api:4.0.1
        Ports:       9042/TCP, 9142/TCP, 7000/TCP, 7001/TCP, 7199/TCP, 8080/TCP, 9103/TCP, 9000/TCP
        Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
        Liveness:    http-get http://:8080/api/v0/probes/liveness delay=15s timeout=10s period=15s #success=1 #failure=3
        Readiness:   http-get http://:8080/api/v0/probes/readiness delay=20s timeout=10s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
        Environment:
          METRIC_FILTERS:           deny:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Table deny:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.live_ss_table_count allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Table.LiveSSTableCount allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.live_disk_space_used allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.LiveDiskSpaceUsed allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Table.Pending allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Table.Memtable allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Table.Compaction allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.read allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.write allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.range allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.coordinator allow:org.apache.cassandra.metrics.table.dropped_mutations
          POD_NAME:                 demo-dc1-default-sts-0 (v1:metadata.name)
          NODE_NAME:                 (v1:spec.nodeName)
          DS_LICENSE:               accept
          DSE_AUTO_CONF_OFF:        all
          USE_MGMT_API:             true
          MGMT_API_EXPLICIT_START:  true
          DSE_MGMT_EXPLICIT_START:  true
        Mounts:
          /config from server-config (rw)
          /opt/management-api/configs from metrics-agent-config (rw)
          /var/lib/cassandra from server-data (rw)
          /var/log/cassandra from server-logs (rw)
          /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-cfdtc (ro)
      server-system-logger:
        Image:      k8ssandra/system-logger:v1.18.1
        Port:       <none>
        Host Port:  <none>
        Limits:
          memory:  128M
        Requests:
          cpu:     100m
          memory:  64M
        Environment:
          POD_NAME:         demo-dc1-default-sts-0 (v1:metadata.name)
          NODE_NAME:         (v1:spec.nodeName)
          CLUSTER_NAME:     demo
          DATACENTER_NAME:  dc1
          RACK_NAME:         (v1:metadata.labels['cassandra.datastax.com/rack'])
          NAMESPACE:        k8ssandra-operator (v1:metadata.namespace)
        Mounts:
          /opt/management-api/configs from metrics-agent-config (rw)
          /var/lib/vector from vector-lib (rw)
          /var/log/cassandra from server-logs (rw)
          /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-cfdtc (ro)
    Conditions:
      Type           Status
      PodScheduled   False 
    Volumes:
      server-data:
        Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
        ClaimName:  server-data-demo-dc1-default-sts-0
        ReadOnly:   false
      server-config:
        Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
        Medium:     
        SizeLimit:  <unset>
      server-logs:
        Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
        Medium:     
        SizeLimit:  <unset>
      vector-lib:
        Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
        Medium:     
        SizeLimit:  <unset>
      metrics-agent-config:
        Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
        Name:      demo-dc1-metrics-agent-config
        Optional:  false
      kube-api-access-cfdtc:
        Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
        TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
        ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
        ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
        DownwardAPI:             true
    QoS Class:                   Burstable
    Node-Selectors:              <none>
    Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
    Events:
      Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
      ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
      Warning  FailedScheduling  26m                 default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
      Warning  FailedScheduling  106s (x4 over 21m)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
```

These are the two nodes :

```
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get nodes -n k8ssandra-operator
    NAME                        STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
    k8ssandra-0-control-plane   Ready    control-plane   18h   v1.25.3
    k8ssandra-0-worker          Ready    <none>          18h   v1.25.3
```

node `k8ssandra-0-control-plane` :

```
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get nodes -n k8ssandra-operator
    NAME                        STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
    k8ssandra-0-control-plane   Ready    control-plane   18h   v1.25.3
    k8ssandra-0-worker          Ready    <none>          18h   v1.25.3
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# 
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe node k8ssandra-0-control-plane -n k8ssandra-operator
    Name:               k8ssandra-0-control-plane
    Roles:              control-plane
    Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                        beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                        kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                        kubernetes.io/hostname=k8ssandra-0-control-plane
                        kubernetes.io/os=linux
                        node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=
                        node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers=
    Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
                        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                        volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
    CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:26 +0100
    Taints:             <none>
    Unschedulable:      false
    Lease:
      HolderIdentity:  k8ssandra-0-control-plane
      AcquireTime:     <unset>
      RenewTime:       Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:50:19 +0100
    Conditions:
      Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
      ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
      MemoryPressure   False   Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:48:59 +0100   Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:21 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
      DiskPressure     False   Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:48:59 +0100   Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:21 +0100   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
      PIDPressure      False   Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:48:59 +0100   Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:21 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
      Ready            True    Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:48:59 +0100   Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:50 +0100   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
    Addresses:
      InternalIP:  172.19.0.2
      Hostname:    k8ssandra-0-control-plane
    Capacity:
      cpu:                10
      ephemeral-storage:  2061040144Ki
      hugepages-1Gi:      0
      hugepages-2Mi:      0
      memory:             61714452Ki
      pods:               110
    Allocatable:
      cpu:                10
      ephemeral-storage:  2061040144Ki
      hugepages-1Gi:      0
      hugepages-2Mi:      0
      memory:             61714452Ki
      pods:               110
    System Info:
      Machine ID:                 7fcb4f58ddde4f989494c54b01582c15
      System UUID:                d2f2c6e4-0f58-4c3c-aaf6-f7e04c1add74
      Boot ID:                    9ec8e4bd-a59c-488b-a90c-82b8b4169a50
      Kernel Version:             5.15.0-88-generic
      OS Image:                   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
      Operating System:           linux
      Architecture:               amd64
      Container Runtime Version:  containerd://1.6.9
      Kubelet Version:            v1.25.3
      Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.25.3
    PodCIDR:                      10.244.0.0/24
    PodCIDRs:                     10.244.0.0/24
    ProviderID:                   kind://docker/k8ssandra-0/k8ssandra-0-control-plane
    Non-terminated Pods:          (10 in total)
      Namespace                   Name                                                 CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
      ---------                   ----                                                 ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
      k8ssandra-operator          demo-dc1-default-sts-1                               1 (10%)       1 (10%)     256M (0%)        384M (0%)      57m
      kube-system                 coredns-565d847f94-4c9wd                             100m (1%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (0%)     18h
      kube-system                 coredns-565d847f94-7xph8                             100m (1%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (0%)     18h
      kube-system                 etcd-k8ssandra-0-control-plane                       100m (1%)     0 (0%)      100Mi (0%)       0 (0%)         67m
      kube-system                 kindnet-crr52                                        100m (1%)     100m (1%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      18h
      kube-system                 kube-apiserver-k8ssandra-0-control-plane             250m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         67m
      kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-k8ssandra-0-control-plane    200m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
      kube-system                 kube-proxy-5hs7d                                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
      kube-system                 kube-scheduler-k8ssandra-0-control-plane             100m (1%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
      local-path-storage          local-path-provisioner-684f458cdd-k8llm              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
    Allocated resources:
      (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
      Resource           Requests        Limits
      --------           --------        ------
      cpu                1950m (19%)     1100m (11%)
      memory             560087040 (0%)  792944640 (1%)
      ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)          0 (0%)
      hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)          0 (0%)
      hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)          0 (0%)
    Events:              <none>
```

node `k8ssandra-0-worker` :

```
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe node k8ssandra-0-worker -n k8ssandra-operator
    Name:               k8ssandra-0-worker
    Roles:              <none>
    Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                        beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                        kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                        kubernetes.io/hostname=k8ssandra-0-worker
                        kubernetes.io/os=linux
                        topology.kubernetes.io/zone=region1-zone1
    Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
                        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                        volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
    CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:47 +0100
    Taints:             <none>
    Unschedulable:      false
    Lease:
      HolderIdentity:  k8ssandra-0-worker
      AcquireTime:     <unset>
      RenewTime:       Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:51:22 +0100
    Conditions:
      Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
      ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
      MemoryPressure   False   Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:49:01 +0100   Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:46 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
      DiskPressure     False   Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:49:01 +0100   Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:46 +0100   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
      PIDPressure      False   Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:49:01 +0100   Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:46 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
      Ready            True    Sat, 11 Nov 2023 12:49:01 +0100   Fri, 10 Nov 2023 18:44:57 +0100   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
    Addresses:
      InternalIP:  172.19.0.3
      Hostname:    k8ssandra-0-worker
    Capacity:
      cpu:                10
      ephemeral-storage:  2061040144Ki
      hugepages-1Gi:      0
      hugepages-2Mi:      0
      memory:             61714452Ki
      pods:               110
    Allocatable:
      cpu:                10
      ephemeral-storage:  2061040144Ki
      hugepages-1Gi:      0
      hugepages-2Mi:      0
      memory:             61714452Ki
      pods:               110
    System Info:
      Machine ID:                 affd0d73f2d64762a0c5d2bcf9ab9dd8
      System UUID:                aad75b1b-f55c-4e3e-9cda-84c4c5de9caa
      Boot ID:                    9ec8e4bd-a59c-488b-a90c-82b8b4169a50
      Kernel Version:             5.15.0-88-generic
      OS Image:                   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
      Operating System:           linux
      Architecture:               amd64
      Container Runtime Version:  containerd://1.6.9
      Kubelet Version:            v1.25.3
      Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.25.3
    PodCIDR:                      10.244.1.0/24
    PodCIDRs:                     10.244.1.0/24
    ProviderID:                   kind://docker/k8ssandra-0/k8ssandra-0-worker
    Non-terminated Pods:          (8 in total)
      Namespace                   Name                                                 CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
      ---------                   ----                                                 ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
      cert-manager                cert-manager-775b959d64-hz8bv                        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
      cert-manager                cert-manager-cainjector-97795797f-hmz79              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
      cert-manager                cert-manager-webhook-979c74b9c-pblnd                 0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
      k8ssandra-operator          demo-dc1-default-sts-2                               1 (10%)       1 (10%)     256M (0%)        384M (0%)      17h
      k8ssandra-operator          k8ssandra-operator-7998574dd5-567qq                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
      k8ssandra-operator          k8ssandra-operator-cass-operator-7599b94d9d-s7nrr    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
      kube-system                 kindnet-hr6jp                                        100m (1%)     100m (1%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      18h
      kube-system                 kube-proxy-27g5d                                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         18h
    Allocated resources:
      (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
      Resource           Requests        Limits
      --------           --------        ------
      cpu                1100m (11%)     1100m (11%)
      memory             308428800 (0%)  436428800 (0%)
      ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)          0 (0%)
      hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)          0 (0%)
      hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)          0 (0%)
    Events:              <none>
```

The Pending Persistent Volume Claims is waiting for the Pending Pod to be scheduled:

```
    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pvc -n k8ssandra-operator -o wide
    NAME                                 STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE   VOLUMEMODE
    server-data-demo-dc1-default-sts-0   Pending                                                                        standard       67m   Filesystem
    server-data-demo-dc1-default-sts-1   Bound     pvc-3bb18f4b-611c-42f6-bfd3-798cdf8d76af   5Gi        RWO            standard       18h   Filesystem
    server-data-demo-dc1-default-sts-2   Bound     pvc-47e9d42e-2f67-4901-a0a4-e21e8928d66c   5Gi        RWO            standard       18h   Filesystem


    root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe pvc server-data-demo-dc1-default-sts-0 -n k8ssandra-operator
    Name:          server-data-demo-dc1-default-sts-0
    Namespace:     k8ssandra-operator
    StorageClass:  standard
    Status:        Pending
    Volume:        
    Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/created-by=cass-operator
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=cassandra-demo
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=cass-operator
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=cassandra
                   app.kubernetes.io/version=4.0.1
                   cassandra.datastax.com/cluster=demo
                   cassandra.datastax.com/datacenter=dc1
                   cassandra.datastax.com/rack=default
    Annotations:   <none>
    Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
    Capacity:      
    Access Modes:  
    VolumeMode:    Filesystem
    Used By:       demo-dc1-default-sts-0
    Events:
      Type    Reason               Age                   From                         Message
      ----    ------               ----                  ----                         -------
      Normal  WaitForPodScheduled  4m7s (x262 over 69m)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for pod demo-dc1-default-sts-0 to be scheduled
```

This is the `K8ssandraCluster.yaml` :

```
    # https://docs.k8ssandra.io/install/local/single-cluster-helm/#deploy-the-k8ssandracluster
    # https://docs.k8ssandra.io/tasks/scale/add-nodes/#create-a-cluster
    
    apiVersion: k8ssandra.io/v1alpha1
    kind: K8ssandraCluster
    metadata:
       name: my-k8ssandra
    spec:
       cassandra:
          serverVersion: "4.0.5"
          datacenters:
             - metadata:
                  name: dc1
               size: 2
          softPodAntiAffinity: true
          # Resources must be specified for each Cassandra node when using softPodAntiAffinity
          resources:
             requests:
                cpu: 1
                memory: 2Gi
             limits:
                cpu: 2
                memory: 2Gi
          # It is also recommended to set the JVM heap size
          config:
             jvmOptions:
                heap_initial_size: 1G
                heap_max_size: 1G
          storageConfig:
             cassandraDataVolumeClaimSpec:
                storageClassName: standard
                accessModes:
                   - ReadWriteOnce
                resources:
                   requests:
                      storage: 5Gi
```

What's the root cause of the problem? How to make the pod change its state to `Running` State ?